# Get running python server IP address in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a python flask app running on my server:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 6600))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

And I have a JS script getting information from that app, I don't want to change manually th IP or domain in the JS script every time I deploy or change the domain so I'm asking is there any way for the JS to know the IP or hostname of the python app ?
Here's my structure:
index.py <= main app
**static**
**index.html
**script.js

Thanks

Comment: Make a service on the python server that returns the port number and call that from the javascript.

Comment: Or when you send that script.js, use templating where you would fill the port number dynamically when user requests script.js

Answer (score 0):

Register a domain name and stick with it. Use the domain name in your javascript and/or config.

Make sure that the registrar provides an interface for updating the "A record" (IP address) and point it at your server. Whenever you change IP address, update the A record for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you pretty much have two options at your disposal depending on your setup.

**Option 1:** If your JavaScript code is running on the same machine as your Python script, you could simply always just access it from 127.0.0.1 from your JavaScript code (because binding to 0.0.0.0 will make the Python server accessible from all interfaces, including the loopback interface at 127.0.0.1).

**Option 2:** If your JavaScript code lives on a remote server, your simplest solution is going to be to use some kind of [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service as an intermediary. So you'll end up with two domains for your Python server: one static one available to the rest of the world, like `www.mypythonserver.com`, and one dynamic DNS entry only known by your JavaScript code, like `mypythonserver.noip.me` (hard-coded permanently into your JavaScript code). Both of these domains should always resolve to your Python server's host address, with no manual intervention necessary for the dynamic DNS entry.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `templating` in the script file which would get filled with the port number when user requests the script.

There are many templates available at :

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating

Usually it would be like

```
  // in script.js
   var myport = {{ port }};
```

and in your python code :

```
# if request is for script.js 
# respond with template 
request.send(my_templating_engine('script.js' , port))
```